# How to do long division $1.068 / 40$ without using a calculator?

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

> 1.068 divided by 40.
>
> 1.068 / 40 = ?

How would you do this problem by long division and any other methods to figure this out without using a calculator. Just pencil and paper.

Comment: Is it true that schools no more teach [long division on pen and paper](http://www.mathsisfun.com/long_division.html) ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it (in my head):
\begin{align*}
\frac{1.068}{40}
&= \frac{1}{10^4} \cdot \frac{1068}{4} \\
&= \frac{1}{10^4} \cdot \frac{534}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{10^4} \cdot 267 \\
&= .0267 \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first divide by 4, then adjust the decimal point.  You should be able to do it in your head, no pencil and paper needed except to write down the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method method, then long division is it.  (If you want the "mental math" way, then you recognize that $40=2\times2\times10$, and it's pretty easy to divide by twos and tens.)